# Cancel Main Form closing while some thread runs in back, C# .windows application?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am running a background thread to move some profile data in an windows application. This thread will run priodically on certain interval.

If the user tries to close the form while the thread runs, i should prompt the user about the thread running and should not allow the user to close form. Once its (thread) completed, then only i have to close the form.

If i do it in the 'Form_Closing' event, thread stops (when i debug) and the control 
stays in the form itself.  After closing the form, thread resumes.., not sure of any issues.

How do i effectly handle this?

Answer (score 1):

In the form `Closing` event you could use the `Cancel` property:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy) {
            MessageBox.Show("Thread busy!");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Although this solution will prevent his form from closing, it can be very annoying to the end user if the thread wakes up again the next time that the user attempts to close the form.  An enhancement should be to automatically close the form once the thread is done or send a flag to the thread to indicate that it should not perform its periodic task anymore (the user did want to exit, after all).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to the thread in your form, you can in OnFormClosing event check its [IsAlive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isalive.aspx) property. If it is true then prevent the form from close by [e.Cancel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel.aspx) = !Thread.IsAlive